# How to allow content authors to add icons to links?

Tags: links, fontawesome

Does anybody allow their content authors to add icons to links? If so, how do you do this? I'm considering the best approaches.

I allow them to make links, and to make those links into buttons (the "Styles" menu of WYGWAM has button options when a link is selected, adding the "btn" classes), but I don't yet know of a good way to also allow icon selection. I currently do it by hand with the  tag. But if I can make it easy on content authors to do this, all the better.

Will be using EE5/latest Font Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

How far are you capable and willing to go? One method is to create a plugin for CKEditor:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957156/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-that-calls-a-javascript-function

I've done something like this a few times to add functionality to Wygwam fields. If you choose this route, you'll need to tell Wygwam to load your custom `style.js` file, and you'll need to install your plugin into the core CKEditor files yourself.

Setting a custom `styles.js` file:
https://eeharbor.com/wygwam/documentation/style_set

Where to install plugins for CKEditor (which Wygwam uses):
`{your_web_root}/themes/user/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins`

Based on the SE link I provided, you may be able to add a simple button by just creating your custom `styles.js` file and applying it (quoting code from an answer in the link provided):

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('container'); // bind editor

editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", { // create named command
    exec: function(edt) {
        alert(edt.getData());
    }
});

editor.ui.addButton('SuperButton', { // add new button and bind our command
    label: "Click me",
    command: 'mySimpleCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
});
```

So create your `styles.js` file, add code like above, and set your Wygwam field to use that `styles.js` file.